# Eevee Grease Pencil looks different Rendered then in Viewport

Tags: grease-pencil, eevee-render-engine, 2d

Curious if this is a bug? Its been driving me crazy recently, the rendered result looks different then the view-port in Eevee using grease pencil, especially when using semi-transparent materials as exampled here. View Transform is set to Default. Using the Blender 2.8 Beta.

[image]

Comment: Are you using Filmic when you render? It looks to me like a discrepancy between the viewport color space and the render color space.

Comment: I used both Filmic and Default. It didn't make a difference when it came to using semi-transparent materials. Final render always looks very different in its color space. The example is using the Default color space.

Comment: did you find a solution ? Got the same problem.  Seems that the strokes on the borders are not rendering correctly : https://i.imgur.com/kWdEMPw.jpg

Comment: Open in the Blender bugtracker : https://developer.blender.org/T60538